# MonoGame iOS 60 FPS

Tags: c#, ios, xna, xamarin.ios, monogame

I am developing a MonoGame app (C#) for iOS using Xamarin Studio in Mac OS X. I have the following code in the Game1.cs constructor but the FPS remains stuck at 30 FPS instead of 60 on my iPhone 4 device:

```
TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333 / 2);
```

While on Windows Phone 8 MonoGame defaults to 60 FPS. Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't hang me up on it, but I do believe that Apple has restricted iOS games to run at 30fps, to restrict FPS. I'm not certain, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Apps/Games on mobile device should be restricted to 30fps, if possible, as anything higher will cause massive battery drain, and your user/customer will not be too pleased with that.
I understand that 60fps is the golden standard, but you really need a very compelling case to go to 60fps on mobile.

If you are certain you absolutely, postively, have to go 60fps, the MonoGame source code should provide you with where the 30fps restriction is happening (sorry I can't remember off the top of my head where it is exactly). IIRC we put the 30fps cap in iOS to save developers from having to deal with irrate customers ;).

Comment: I have actually found out that its my iPhone 4 outdated hardware that is limiting my FPS. I have just got an iPhone 5 and the game runs at 60 FPS without adding the above code, so this limit you mention must have been removed.

Comment: Could well be. I've not worked on the MG codebase for a while.